# Can I display whitespace characters in iTerm2

Tags: iterm2, whitespace

In most text editors I can display whitespace characters, e.g. tabs as arrows `⟶` , spaces as middle dots `·`

Is it possible to do this in iTerm2?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it directly. Maybe if you had a custom font that shows indents.

Alternatively, [bats](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#show-non-printable-characters) does allow you to show non-printable characters.

If you are using VIM, you can also add nicer tabs with:

```
"Show nice tabs
"===============
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<
set list
```